# Angular 2 ngOnInit variables

Tags: angular

I'm fairly new to angular2 and I'm kinda stuck on something.

The Service:

```
 getReports() {
            return this.http.get(GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL + 'report/l', {headers: this.headers}).map(res => res.json());
        }
```

The controller:

```
document:any;
id:any;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.documentTypeService.getType(id).subscribe(data => {
document=data;
id= data.id;
console.log(id);
});
console.log(id); //undefined
    }
```

I need the id outside ngOnInit() any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning id as below

`this.id = data.id;`

You can now console.log the id outside the ngOnIt() as below

`console.log(this.id)`

Comment: the first console.log works but second return undefined

Comment: The reason why the second console.log() returns undefined is because `this.id` is initialized with the value once the async call is complete so whatever you intended to do with  `this.id` should be done inside the subscribe() method .

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your value(data.id) to the variable(id) just like this.

```
document:any;
    id:any;
        ngOnInit() {
          this.documentTypeService.getType(id).subscribe(data => {
    document=data;
    this.id= data.id;
    console.log(this.id);
    });
    console.log(this.id); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write `this.id` to access class fields. Like this:

```
document:any;
id:any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.documentTypeService.getType(id).subscribe(data => {
    this.document = data;
    this.id = data.id;
    console.log(this.id); 
  });
  console.log(this.id); 
}
```

Second input is `undefined`, it means that `this.id` is still empty when you call `console.log` - they are executing synchronously and you try to access data which does not yet exist.

Read about async\await.